# Xampp is running but wont show anything on localhost

Tags: php, xampp

My xampp is running but wont show anything i am writing in the index.php file.
I have disabled the ports on Skype but still doesnt work properly.

http://prnt.sc/dh7xwv

http://prnt.sc/dh7y1d

And my path is correct...

Comment: put your project inside htdocs

Comment: It is in htdocs, couldnt provide that screenshot, because i can post only 2 links

Comment: localhost/projectname or localhost:port/projectname?

Comment: What happens if browse on port 443? https://127.0.0.1/

Comment: Hey guys tnx for replying, but i am newbie in php so i made a beginner mistake, <php    ?> instead of <?php     ?>, sorry for bothering.

Comment: None one here noticed it so don't worry about it. Oh... and don't forget to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

By the way the mistake was a beginner mistake instead of < ? php    ?> i typed < php ? >

Answer (score 0):

just completely close the skype app from system and try to access http://localhost/ you will get a landing page if apache server is running